# Where to create multiple variables?

Tags: python, global-variables, user-input

I have some python code which reads in a series of user-specified variables from another file, including some `if` statements for variables that aren't always selected by the user. An example of the code I have is as follows:

```
import sys   

if __name__=="__main__":
#Read-in user input file     
  filename = sys.argv[-1]

#Import user-defined parameters
  m = __import__(filename) 

  directory = m.directory
  experimentNumber = m.experimentNumber
  dataInput = m.dataInput
  outputFile = m.outputFile
  save_flag = m.save_flag
  cores = m.cores
  npts1 = m.npts1
  npts2_recorded = m.npts2_recorded
  weightingFuncNameDim2 = m.weightingFuncNameDim2
  weightingFuncParamsDim2 = m.weightingFuncParamsDim2

  if int(m.ndim) >= 2:  
    weightingFuncNameDim3 = m.weightingFuncNameDim3
    weightingFuncParamsDim3 = m.weightingFuncParamsDim3

  else:
    weightingFuncNameDim3 = '-'
    weightingFuncParamsDim3 = '-'
```

In total there are around 50 of these variables imported from the user-defined file. The imported variables are all used by other functions later in the code. The way I have coded this seems to set these as global variables so they can easily be used by other variables. However, is there a more pythonic way to do this? However, I'm not sure what the best approach would be to make these variables available without passing 50 variables into each function (cumbersome).

Comment: Put the variables into a dictionary or class, and pass that to the various functions that need it.

Comment: Further to Kendall’s comment - this pythonic way of doing things is called object oriented programming...

Comment: Is that a thing? I was under the impression that the pythonic way just tended to use more python-unique functions.

Comment: Could you give an example for the above. How would you pass a variable(s) created in one class to another class?